# Error after moving wordpress blog

Tags: migration

i was working on a wordpress blog under a test domain (example.com/blog/) and now i want to move it under its own domain which is on the same server but different vhost.

After googling a bit i found a way to do it by simply moving the files however this generated a 500 internal error. This is (almost) normal because the site reads the old site location. I had to update it with the follwing code placed inside the functions.php

```
<?php
update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
update_option('home','http://example.com');
?>
```

I tried with this code to reload the page cuple of times as the wordpress docs said but again nothing!
I also updated the database to the example.com but still nothing.
Is it possible to fix it? Also can i simply change the vhost location to the /arduino/ folder?

My server config: Ubuntu 13 Nginx MariaDB

Current location: /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/arduino/ 
Desired location: /var/www/clients/client0/web7/web/

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Im using ISPconfig to create virtual hosts

Comment: Go to PHPMyAdmin, download the whole database as a SQL file, open it on a text editor, search and replace old domain with new domain. Upload file back to database. I would recommend adding to a new database and then updating the config file - it's easier that way if you want to revert the changes.

Comment: To avoid in future you could also consider getting Delicious Brain's WP Migrate plug-in. It takes care of all the database rewrites and makes migrating the databases very easy.

Comment: @gdaniel as i said i changed the database domain but nothing

Comment: I wasn't sure you changed just in one option field, or the entire database.

Comment: i've changed the 'home' and the 'siteurl'

Comment: @gdaniel's suggestion might throw off your widgets and other odds and ends because some of the data in the WP database is serialized. Check out [the WP Codex article on migration](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and use a tool like [Peach](http://petesaia.github.io/Peach/) for your database to handle serialized data.

Comment: I think im gonne change nginx domain vhost to point the on specific folder